# Unable to update android studio from 3.1 to 3.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

I am trying to update android studio from 3.1 to 3.1.1 it showing below error while patch

[image]

Error Log

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot delete: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\lib\external-system-rt.jar
    at com.intellij.updater.Utils.tryDelete(Utils.java:108)
    at com.intellij.updater.Utils.access$000(Utils.java:15)
    at com.intellij.updater.Utils$1.visitFile(Utils.java:71)
    at com.intellij.updater.Utils$1.visitFile(Utils.java:68)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2670)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
    at com.intellij.updater.Utils.delete(Utils.java:68)
    at com.intellij.updater.BaseUpdateAction.replaceUpdated(BaseUpdateAction.java:118)
    at com.intellij.updater.UpdateAction.doApply(UpdateAction.java:77)
    at com.intellij.updater.PatchAction.apply(PatchAction.java:201)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.lambda$apply$2(Patch.java:401)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.forEach(Patch.java:473)
    at com.intellij.updater.Patch.apply(Patch.java:392)
    at com.intellij.updater.PatchFileCreator.apply(PatchFileCreator.java:78)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner.install(Runner.java:355)
    at com.intellij.updater.Runner.main(Runner.java:133)
```

Can anyone provide the solution for this

Comment: Have you looked at the log? There may be more details...

Comment: does your user has admin rights ?

Comment: Maybe it is not admin permission. Give permission to the folder.

Comment: @MattJones there is same error unable to delete lib\external-system-rt.jar

Comment: @Lucifer yes i have admin rights

Comment: ok, @MJM, close your studio, and try with run as administrator option.

Comment: @K.Sopheak permission to which folder?before this it's working fine

Comment: @Lucifer it's not working,i have updated the question with error log

Comment: try manually cut & paste that .jar file to d: and then retry with update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's resolved after only restarting a system.